# Object.assign & dynamic css styling for Flexbox - codepen specific

Tags: javascript, css, ecmascript-6, flexbox

I am putting together a small flexbox demo for a project with some examples. I am using Object.assign to add some styles dynamically to some flex-items when a user changes the values in the dropdown.

But I have a small error **only** occurring in codepen - If I copy my code into an editor and run locally on chrome no issues arise.

**To reproduce**: Try changing a value on a flex item on the right column and open the console.

I know I can just run this in a browser and forget codepen but I do prefer using it for babel without having to run a build step and would like to find out if I am doing something wrong and if it can be improved.

```
'Uncaught TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object'
```

Line 56 is where the error occurs.

https://codepen.io/jreynolds90/pen/mmxewW?editors=1111

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem appears to be this line: `const flexItems = [...document.querySelectorAll('.flex-item')];`. If you set a breakpoint for the line triggering the error (Chrome DevTools, for example) you realize, in that particular moment `flexItem` is `[div.flex-item, div.flex-item, div.flex-item]` (an array, and array.style is undefined). This is no surprise since if you take a look at `flexItems` (plural) in that moment, you see it is `[NodeList(3)]` (read: Array of three NodeList), hence the first element in the forEach is the Array.

Just use: `const flexItems = document.querySelectorAll('.flex-item');` and your code works just fine: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/WjzQqL?editors=1111

Comment: Ahh good pick up! Thank you, thought I had to convert it before looping over.